# Learning from time-series data to predict time-series (not forecasting)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science

I have a number of datasets where each of them contains a number of input variables (lets say 3) as time series and an output variable, also as a time series and all over the same time period.

Each of these series has the same number of datapoints (say 1000*10 if 10 second data was gathered at 1000Hz).

I want to learn from this data and given a new dataset with 3 time serieses for input variables, I want to predict the time series for the output variable.

I will write the problem below in some non-English notation. I will avoid using terms like features, sample, target etc because since I haven't formulated the problem for any algorithm, I don't want to speculate what will be what.

Datasets to learn from look like this:

```
dataset1:{Inputs=(timSeries1,timSeries2,timSeries3), Output=(timSeriesOut)}
dataset2:{Inputs=(timSeries1,timSeries2,timSeries3), Output=(timSeriesOut)}
dataset3:{Inputs=(timSeries1,timSeries2,timSeries3), Output=(timSeriesOut)}
.
.
datasetn:{Inputs=(timSeries1,timSeries2,timSeries3), Output=(timSeriesOut)}
```

Now, given a new (timSeries1, timSeries2, timSeries3) I want to predict (timSeriesOut)

```
datasetPredict:{Inputs=(timeSeries1,timSeries2,timSeries3), Output = ?}
```

What technique should I use and how should the problem be formulated? Should I just break it as separate learning problem for each time stamp with three features and one target (either for that or next timestamp)?

Thank you all!

Comment: There are lots of options here... Do you know anything a priori about some model the data should fit or is it just essentially random data?

Comment: it is not totally random data. It is physical vibration; so if I look at the time data in frequency domain, I may see same peaks across several time series. So I am happy to pose the problem like that (convert it from time domain to frequency domain). However, other than this there is nothing known a priori. Thank you Alex!

Comment: If you don't need a model that is "simple", you might try using an LSTM: it can learn how current and past inputs affect the output. That said, this approach would use anything you might know a prior about the dynamics of your system (e.g. the laws of physics).